# Promise.race function to compare the timeout

Tags: javascript, testing, promise, automated-tests, testcafe

I have a piece of code( a test runner) that should run the code and return the result, I want to put a time restriction for each test case so I use Promise.race but unfortunately it's not working

```
const createTestCafe = require('testcafe');
let testcafe         = null;

createTestCafe('localhost', 1337, 1338)
    .then(tc => {
        testcafe       = tc;
        const runner   = testcafe.createRunner();


        const runPromise = runner
            .src(['/test.js'])
            .browsers(['chrome'])
            .run({skipJsErrors:true});

        const deadlinePromise = new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5000))
        .then(new Error('request timeout'))

      return Promise.race([runPromise, deadlinePromise])
    })

    .catch(failedCount => {
        console.log('Tests failed: ' + failedCount);
        testcafe.close();
    });
```

runPromise is my testcase which always returns 10 secs or 11 secs and deadlinePromise I have set 5sec, its always running my testcase and returning the secs but I what I want to achieve is the testcase to fail since it's taking longer than 5 sec, how do I do that??

Comment: `then()` requires a function argument ===> `.then(new Error('request timeout'))`

Comment: I am new to this Promise area, i am not understanding, can you help me with the code.

Comment: .then( () => {new Error('request timeout')} )

Comment: If you do `.then(() => { throw new Error('request timeout'); })`, you should get the `Tests failed` log from your `catch` statement after 5 seconds. Do you not?

Comment: @Bergi thanks , i missed the 'throw' previously now the catch statement is catching the failed test cases after 5 secs however when i increased the timeout for 20 secs i was assuming this should pass since my tests is taking 12 secs where as timeout is 20secs but still its landing in the catch statement. How do i achieve that?

Comment: @TS0306 Doesn't `runPromise` fulfill after the 12 seconds? Try adding a `.then(() => console.log("test finished"))` before the `Promise.race` call.

Answer (score 2):

I'm making a heavy assumption that all the other stuff in your code works as intended. But, I see two major issues that cause this code not to work

1. `.then(new Error('request timeout'))`: As @charlietfl called out, you need a function argument. `then` requires this but you're not giving it one.
2. `Promise.race([runPromise, deadlinePromise])` returns a promise, not a resolved one. I added `async` flag to your function so you can just `await` it (or else you've need another `.then( ... )` etc...)

Updated code

```
const createTestCafe = require('testcafe');
let testcafe         = null;

createTestCafe('localhost', 1337, 1338)
    .then(async (tc) => { // Added async so you can use await
        testcafe       = tc;
        const runner   = testcafe.createRunner();
        const runPromise = runner
            .src(['/test.js'])
            .browsers(['chrome'])
            .run({skipJsErrors:true});

        const deadlinePromise = new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5000))
            .then( d => new Error('request timeout')); // First Issue: `.then` requires a function argument. 

        return await Promise.race([runPromise, deadlinePromise]) // Second Issue: You need to actually run this
    })

    .catch(failedCount => {
        console.log('Tests failed: ' + failedCount);
        testcafe.close();
    });
```

Comment: No, please don't add `await`. The `return` was entirely fine. If you want to convert the code to `async`/`await` style, do it for *every* `then` or `catch` call.

Comment: If you don't add `await`, there's an assumption that the caller of this method is either `awaiting` the response or using `then`.

Comment: The caller of the callback is the `then` function, which *does* use `then` to resolve the outer promise (the one onto which the OP chained the `.catch(…)`). No assumptions necessary.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "trigger promise to run"? A promise doesn't run, it doesn't represent a task, it's just an observable proxy an asynchronous result. And yes, a `createTestCafe(...).then(...)` is right in that code.

Comment: No, absolutely not. A promise is resolved by the routine that created it, the `then` method has nothing to do with that. `Promise.resolve` does (as the name says) immediately resolve. The promise returned by a `.then()` call is resolved with the result of the callback function when that runs.

Comment: `Promise.resolve(44)` returns a resolved promise. The promise returned by `Promise.resolve(44).then(...)` is (or will be) resolved unless the then callback throws or returns a promise that eventually settles on its error path. No amount of chaining `.then()` or `.catch()` will affect the "upstream" elements of the chain. Each element settles in its own right, in accordance with the immediately preceding element's settlement and the behaviour of its own callback(s), and so on down the chain.

Comment: Should the `testcafe` instance not also be closed when `Promise.race()` settles on its success path?

Comment: hello All I tried the solution provided by both @Bergi and mwilson but still it doesnot work. ts always running my testcase and returning 12 secs where as i have given 5 secs for the TIMEOUT. Help needed please. I have tried with or without async/await. What more do i need to do?

Comment: Change the `const deadlinePromise = ...` expression to `const deadlinePromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(reject, 5000, new Error('request timeout')))`.